# drop rows from a Pandas dataframe based on which rows have missing values in another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I'm trying to drop rows with missing values in any of several dataframes.

They all have the same number of rows, so I tried this:

```
model_data_with_NA = pd.concat([other_df,
                                standardized_numerical_data,
                                encode_categorical_data], axis=1)
ok_rows = ~(model_data_with_NA.isna().all(axis=1))
model_data = model_data_with_NA.dropna()
assert(sum(ok_rows) == len(model_data))
```

False!

As a newbie in Python, I wonder why this doesn't work? Also, is it better to use hierarchical indexing? Then I can extract the original columns from model_data.

Answer (score 0):

**In Short**

I believe the `all` in `~(model_data_with_NA.isna().all(axis=1))` should be replaced with `any`.

The reason is that `all` checks here if every value in a row is missing, and `any` checks if one of the values is missing.

**Full Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[1, np.nan]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [1, 2, np.nan]})

model_data_with_na = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
ok_rows = ~(model_data_with_na.isna().any(axis=1))
model_data = model_data_with_na.dropna()
assert(sum(ok_rows) == len(model_data))
```

`model_data_with_na`

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | nan | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | nan | nan |

`model_data`

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |